# Шаблон сборки Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, mingw-w64

Может есть какие-то шаблоны, фермы, kit и т.д. для сборки Qt? Каждый раз собираю Qt, как ни минном поле, никогда не знаешь где вылетит ошибка. В основном приходится собирать 5, 6 версии под Windows и Debian -opensource -static. Для каждой сборки постоянно приходится искать сборочный софт нужной версии mingw, cmake, ninja, python, msys2 и т.д. Наверняка, кто-то тоже так мучается каждый раз

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

```
vcpkg install qtbase # для Qt6
vcpkg install qt5-base
```

На сайте Qt есть видео-туториал
https://www.qt.io/resources/videos/building-a-qt-application-with-modern-cmake-and-vcpkg